# How to construct a varchar column in 'HH:mm' to datetime format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Bus` with one column `busStopTime` in the table as a varchar field which holds the time in `'HH:mm'` format. I am trying to convert it to a datetime so that I can compare with other datetime field.

But I am not able to convert it.

Example:
`BUS`

```
busName route   busStopTime busStartTime tripNumber
----------------------------------------------------------

690      ABC      03:30        04:30        1

690      ABC      05:30        06:30        2

690      ABC      07:30        08:30        3
```

Here I have three rows as a example with same busNames but different timings.I wanted to write a query so on a given time (in DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS)I can know the trip number for that particular time using the busStopTime and busStartime columns.

I have no other code with me to share but hoping I would get some clue on how to convert it using SQL query?

Comment: Why did you tag `java` if you're asking for SQL-only solution, and don't want any Java solution?

Comment: @Andreas, question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `datetime` using addition.  For the time on the current date:

```
select (convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())) +
        convert(datetime, busStartTime)
       ) today_busStartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, using JDBC, get the string value and parse it to a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) (added in Java 8), which has methods for easy comparison to other `LocalTime` objects, and for manipulating the time value, e.g. adding 15 minutes to it.

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(rs.getString("busStopTime"));
```

If using Java 6 or 7, use the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But If I wanted to do in Java then my table has no  such kind of uniqueness to give single row and everytime I need to deal with multiple rows. So I am looking for a solution where I can compare two times  to get a unique row in SQL server.

Comment: @SanthoshKThadka Huh? Sorry, I didn't understand that at all. --- You tagged the question "java", but you don't want a Java solution? --- Time values in `HH:mm` format happens to be directly comparable as string values, meaning that they can easily be compared and sorted directly in SQL, so I've no clue what it is you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wanted to convert the string to date time in SQL query only.

Comment: @SanthoshKThadka For what purpose? --- And it cannot really be converted to a "**date** time", since there is no date part.

Comment: I have two columns in SQL table with same format(HH:mm) and I will use them to retrieve data between those times using another datetime as input to that query.

Comment: @SanthoshKThadka So do that: `where ? between busStartTime and busStopTime` will work just fine for Java string value formatted as `HH:mm`, e.g. `stmt.setString(1, "09:16")`.

Comment: So you want me to take HH:mm from a date object and query?

Comment: @SanthoshKThadka I have apparently no idea what you want. Perhaps you could edit the question and clarify it. Examples would definitely help.